# Orphaned Answer Not Associated to My Account

Tags: bug, status-completed

While perusing a post I came upon a reply ([see OmegaMan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110171/how-to-update-linq-to-sql-dbml-file#OmegaMan)) that I have done and noticed my name but no link into my account.

My current account shows my first post as April 8, 2010 and this post was made almost a year before that.... so I am wondering what is happening.

Are there other orphaned `OmegaMan` answers written by me but not associated?

[image]

The post has been flagged for attention.

### Update

Just to be clear, I did post this answer on the account `OmegaMan` which I have had since first stepping foot on SO. Sometime later after that post, a year(?), I ended up switching my ID provider for the account away from the OpenId to the StackExchange account login.

Comment: I can only speculate, but since usernames aren't unique; someone else could have had the same name, and deleted themselves way back when

Comment: No, it is my handiwork...the link should point to a Connect bug on MSDN I wrote...but either the link is bad or MSDN is no longer showing the bug.

Comment: Did you post that original question as an unregistered user, or use a different account, and then only later on register an account?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is if you had multiple accounts and they got merged, but I thought merging would show your current account.  Weird.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables If there were multiple accounts and they *didn't* get merged, this could maybe happen.

Comment: @Servy For my account I used an open source Id which pointed to my blog, but had problems and switched to a SO login.

Comment: @Servy - yeah, not sure what I was thinking there

Comment: Well, where were you 6 years ago?  Are you sure you remember?  I do have a vague memory of you posting to SO and not coming back for a while.  You don't get a squeak out of SO when you accidentally create a new account.

Comment: @HansPassant yes the account was *fallow* for a stretch; but I don't believe I had to create a new account...but that scenario you present  seems plausible. But wouldn't I be stopped from using `OmegaMan` if the account was in use?

Comment: No.  There are well over a thousand John Smith accounts.  Hate that guy.

Comment: Considering the date you joined is March 3rd, 2010, I'd say it's definitely a case of you accidentally created a new account when you switched logins. It looks like the original account was deleted at some point after that, but the answer had upvotes and therefore was kept around. At least, that's my guess based on what I can get to/see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Shog sorted out the post ownership issue, so the post ownership is now yours.

It looks like the unused account was deleted as an abandoned one.